# SQL Server 2008 - Running SQL statements from command line

Tags: sql-server

Can someone please advice - how can we run SQL Query statement from command line. We want to create a batch file which will have SQL statements which end user can execute from command line.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Just typ sqlcmd /? on a commandline, the given hints should help.